# Что возвращает getChildAt?

Tags: android, java

Добрый день! Что возвращает строка

```
RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup
                .getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
```

А точнее меня интересует, что же возвращает `getChildAt`?

Вот эта строчка

```
int checkedIndex = group.indexOfChild(checkedRadioButton);
```

возвращает индекс нажатой радиокнопки.

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эмм... Почитать об этом в [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) вам не позволяет религия?